# How to store range(in geocircle radius form) in mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema

I am building an e-commerce application. Every store has a delivery range so i want to set delivery range of every store in the database to show the store only to those who falls in the delivery range.

Store Schema.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const sellerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type: {
            type: "String",
            enum:['Point']
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            index: '2dsphere'
        }
    },
    owner: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    items: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "items"
    }],
    contact: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    loginId: {
        index:true,
        unique: true,
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const sellerModel = mongoose.model("sellers",sellerSchema);
module.exports = sellerModel;
```

Comment: Hi.  Where are the stores?  City?  Zip Code?  Address ?  You need to have something that references these locations within our solar system and our galaxy before any spatial operations can be performed.

Comment: I am storing latitude and longitude of stores. By storing latitude and longitude it will be easy to map them exactly on google maps.